# PC Lint, err 613 and "complicated" if

Tags: c++, if-statement, nullptr, pc-lint

```
int* ptrF();
void f()
{
    int* p = ptrF();
    bool pOK = p && true;
    if (pOK)
        *p = 12; // Lint thinks p might be nullptr here
}
```

Lint gives a warning

```
C:\lint_test\nullptr_with_init.cpp(8): Issue 613: (Warning -- Possible use of null pointer 'p' in argument to operator 'unary *' [Reference: file C:\lint_test\nullptr_with_init.cpp: line 6])
```

Does anyone know if there is a setting to **make Lint more "clever" and to see that pOK cannot be true if p == nullptr**?

This would be much better than changing the code or suppressing the warning like this

```
        *p = 12; //lint !e613
```

Edit:

[Pc Lint, how to suppress err 613(Possible use of null ponter) for class with init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287883/pc-lint-how-to-suppress-err-613possible-use-of-null-ponter-for-class-with-ini)
is an absolutely different question. That one is about how to supress a warning.
This one is about how to make Lint check "complicated" if-statements (if possible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pc Lint, how to suppress err 613(Possible use of null ponter) for class with init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287883/pc-lint-how-to-suppress-err-613possible-use-of-null-ponter-for-class-with-ini)

Comment: ^^  Merely boils down to the same point.

Comment: The only common part of these 2 questions is that they are about err 613.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems like in this case adding conversion from pointer to bool will help

```
bool pOK = (bool)p && true;
```